# Django model design for Shopping List with use of ManytoMany relationship?

Tags: python, django, django-models, database-design, model

I am working on making a Django app to handle multiple shopping lists. Which should have ManytoMany field, Item model, or List model? is this model optimal?

A list can have many items, 0 or more sublists, 0 or more associated stores. most of these relationship looks like many to many. An item can be in many list, a store can be associated to many list. sublist is just putting the item in categories so I can also remove this model and add a category attribute to items. But, the most confusing part is :

**Item has m2m fields for List but should it also have m2m field for Sublist? a List need not have sublist so the item can be part of list or sublist in a list (like a folder/file structure)**

models.py:

```
class List(models.Model):
    name = models.Charfield(max_length=125)
    date = models.DateField(default=django.utils.timezone.now)

class Store(models.Model) :
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    store = models.ManyToManyField(List)

class Item(models.Model):
    item = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    price = models.FloatField(default=0.0)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=128, default=None)
    checked = models.BooleanField(default=None)
    store = models.ManyToManyField(List)

class SubList(models.Model):
    name = models.Charfield(max_length=256)
    parent_list = models.ForeignKey(List)
    items = models.ManyToManyField(Item)
```

Answer (score 0):

I usually follow this rule to choose if the relation between two models is many to many. For instance, the relation of an `Author` and a `Book` he/she wrote can be modeled as many to many field, because both `Author` and `Book` have unique identities. A unique `Book` can have one or many unique `Author`s and a unique `Author` can write one or many unique `Book`s.

On the other hand, the same book can be considered an `Item` in a `Store`. In this case it is not unique anymore, because `Item` can be any book or other item in that store, but the store itself is a unique identity, so one to many relation.

In your case, I think you can manage all the relations with `ForeignKey` or one to many field.

Comment: sure, how about item is not unique but just a memeber of the list. For example you can buy a chair from IKEA or from Walmart or Amazon. In the list Chair will be added but it can relate to many store